# Full calendar: On click of time slot wrong time selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

[image]I have used full calender in my project. 
DefaultView is weekview.

In week view when click in between 5pm to 6pm(Date:21-11-2015) timeslot, it gives perfect time slot timing with 21-11-2015 5:00pm to 6:00pm.But when i 
click on 7pm to 8pm(Date:21-11-2015) timeslot it gives me wrong time with 22-11-2015 7:00pm to 8:00pm.

I don't know how date change to next day. Actual date must be 21-11-2015 7:00pm to 8:00pm.

My timezone is Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30).

Comment: some code or JSfiddle may be...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i got solution.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
{
       alert(date); // Gives Sat Nov 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0000
}
```

Here date gives me Sat Nov 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0000. And my timezone is Asia/kolkata (GMT+05:30).  so it automatically add 05:30 hours to 19:00:00. So date is converted to next day.

For this problem i do following process.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
    {

var tzDifference = date.getTimezoneOffset() //this gives me timezone difference of local and UTC time in minutes
var offsetTime = new Date(date.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000); //this will calculate time in point of view local time and set date
    }
```

And i get date which i want.

Comment: Did you open an issue with FullCalendar? To me, this is a bug in how it handles dates.